# Find value greater than level - Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In a time series (ordered tuples), what's the most efficient way to find the first time a criterion is met?

In particular, what's the most efficient way to determine when a value goes over 100 for the value of a column in a pandas data frame?

I was hoping for a clever vectorized solution, and not having to use `df.iterrows()`.

For example, for price or count data, when a value exceeds 100. I.e. df['col'] > 100.

```
              price
date 
2005-01-01     98
2005-01-02     99
2005-01-03     100
2005-01-04     99
2005-01-05     98
2005-01-06     100
2005-01-07     100
2005-01-08     98
```

but for potentially very large series. Is it better to iterate (slow) or is there a vectorized solution?

A `df.iterrows()` solution could be:

```
for row, ind in df.iterrows():
    if row['col'] > value_to_check:
        breakpoint = row['value_to_record'].loc[ind]
        return breakpoint
return None
```

But my question is more about efficiency (potentially, a vectorized solution that will scale well).

Comment: An example of your data would help this question gain traction.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've edited the question - hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 27):

Try this: "> 99"

```
df[df['price'].gt(99)].index[0]
```

returns `"2"`, the second index row.

all row indexes greater than 99

```
df[df['price'].gt(99)].index
Int64Index([2, 5, 6], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: i don't think this answers the core of the question, they're asking : is there a vectorized numpy operation which is like an iterator, so that it will lazily return values (we only care about the first one) rather than iterating over the whole array before returning

Answer (score 5):

This will return the index value of the first occurrence of 100 in the series:

```
 index_value = (df['col'] - 100).apply(abs).idxmin()
```

If there is no value exactly 100, it should return the index of the closest value.

Comment: Solution worked for my needs, which is getting the first occurrence for each grouping. In this case I created a column = (df['col'] - 100).apply(abs), then did the groupby and used idxmin() as the function. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

numpy argmax returns when it finds the first True value. Numpy is a pandas dependency and is then available for you directly :).

```py
df.iloc[np.argmax(df['col'] > 100)]
```